# Como exibir uma mensagem após excluir um registro utilizando php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho uma página com uma lista de dados e para cada registro tenho a opção excluir. Quando eu clico no botão excluir, antes de executar a ação ele verifica em um arquivo controlador qual ação foi solicitada para só então fazer a execução do código de exclusão.

O fluxo de ações segue mais ou menos assim:

**Clique do Botão** => **Verificação no Controller** => **Executa Ação**

Eu tentei printar em tela uma mensagem após a execução do código, porém a mensagem é exibida na página de controller. O que não é certo pois essa página não deveria exibir nada, sendo apenas uma ponte entre a solicitação e a ação desejada.

Para solicitar a exclusão eu estou utilizando o método post. Seria possível fazer a mensagem de confirmação aparecer na página aonde existe a listagem? Caso seja possível, como poderia ser feito?

Comment: Isso é um Ajax?

Comment: @dvd Faço isso diretamente no PHP, nesse caso eu não utilizo Ajax na requisição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer isso utilizando AJAX. O código fica mais ou menos assim:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: URL-DA-SUA-REQUISICAO,
  data: DADOS-DA-SUA-REQUISICAO,
  success: function sucesso(dados) {
    document.write('Concluido')
  },
  error: function erro(error) {
    document.write('Ops, um erro ocorreu')
    console.error(error)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Vale lembrar, que nesse caso, a função do campo `error` somente será chamada caso ocorra um erro na requisição ou quando o status HTTP retornado seja um status de erro.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, resolveu meu problema.